# 'go test' returns error "gocql: no response received from cassandra within timeout period."

Tags: go, cassandra, connection-timeout, gocql

So i want to test out an API that interacts with Cassandra on my local machine. In my `func TestMain(m *testing.M)` function, i want to clear the tables before running the tests. The `TestMain` function looks like this...

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    keyspace = "staging"
    cassandra.SetKeyspace(keyspace)

    client = http.DefaultClient

    // Ensure all tables are empty before tests run
    err := ClearAllTables()
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorf("Failed to clear all tables: %v.", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Run tests
    statusCode := m.Run()

    os.Exit(statusCode)
}
```

The `ClearAllTables` function looks like this...

```
func ClearAllTables() (err error) {

    // Create a DB session
    session := cassandra.CreateSession()
    defer session.Close()

    // Get names of all existing tables
    tableNameList := []string{"cliques", "users"}

    // Remove all rows from each table
    var count int
    for _, tableName := range tableNameList {

        if err := session.Query(`TRUNCATE TABLE ` + tableName).Exec(); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

For some reason when i try to TRUNCATE the table, Cassandra times out, and i get the error...

```
level=error msg="Failed to clear all tables: gocql: no response received from cassandra within timeout period."
```

This only seems to happen when i test the program. I wrote a snippet of code in the main function that works fine.

```
func main () {
    session := cassandra.CreateSession()
    defer session.Close()

    if err := session.Query(`TRUNCATE TABLE cliques`).Exec(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Table truncated") //works
}
```

I also wrote a snippet of code that returns some rows from the database, and that also works fine in the main function.

Here is how i create my cassandra session...

```
// CreateSession connect to a cassandra instance
func CreateSession() *gocql.Session {
    // Connect to the cluster
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1")
    cluster.Keyspace = "staging"
    cluster.ProtoVersion = 4
    cluster.CQLVersion = "3.0.0"
    cluster.Consistency = gocql.One

    session, err := cluster.CreateSession()
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorf("Failed to connect to Cassandra: %v.", err)
    }
    return session
}
```

I'm i missing anything, Why would Cassandra work fine with `go run main.go` but doesn't work with `go test`?

Comment: What does `getAllTableNames` return? Your code isn't identical in both cases.

Comment: getAlltables just returns a slice of all my table names. I tested it out and it works. In the second case, I just hard coded the table name

Comment: How would someone reproduce this? Have `getAllTableNames` return just `cliques`. Does that work?

Comment: I have removed the `getAllTableNames` method call. Could the problem be from the Cassandra cluster running on port 127.0.0.1? When i debug my test, it prints this on the console.. `API server listening at:127.0.0.1:28132`. does some internal code use the cassandra port already?